# Quando se encontra a real necessidade da utilização de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, front-end

Sou novo no mundo de desenvolvimento, e me iniciei pelo Front-End. Venho procurando me especializar em HTML, CSS e especialmente JavaScript, porém ao longo do tempo venho percebendo que com o avanço dessas linguagens e, especificamente o CSS em sua 3ª geração já consegue, sozinho, fazer diversos efeitos visuais que antes só eram possíveis com o JavaScript (um slider ou qualquer outro tipo de animação). De tal forma, ainda me deparei com poucas situações em que o JavaScript é realmente necessário, como a abertura de um modal ou uma validação de formulário, por exemplo. Em quais ocasiões o JavaScript é realmente necessário, e não apenas opcional ? A linguagem corre risco de ser substituída de fato pelo CSS, ou ainda existe um grande número de casos em que apenas o JS pode realizar uma tarefa (seja um efeito visual ou não).

Comment: O Javascript serve para muito mais (mas muito :p) do que trabalhar efeitos visuais

Comment: Como o que, exatamente ? Essa é minha dúvida...

Comment: Basta dares uma pequena olhada vertical na documentação para o verificares. Manipulação de dados, tratamento de acções, por aí fora

Comment: Julgo compreender o que tens em mente na pergunta. Porém as respostas são inúmeras e basicamente CSS e JavaScript cumprem funções diferentes e não podem substituir uma a outra. Um exemplo de algo que não podes fazer só com CSS: [(link)](https://rawgit.com/Dissimulate/Tearable-Cloth/master/index.html).

Comment: @Sergio, obrigado pela resposta, agradeço por ter colocado a pergunta em hold, pois realmente é uma pergunta que pode ter como resposta diversas opiniões, porém eu desconhecia essa regra do fórum. Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Não, javascript jamais será substituído pelo CSS simplesmente por se tratarem de dois mundos diferentes.
O CSS não e uma linguagem de programação.

Ao invés de falar, falar e falar aqui um monte de coisa e não passar da minha opinião, vou te ensinar um negócio:
Entra num site qualquer (o Facebook, por exemplo) pelo Google Chrome. Aperta F12 pra abrir as "Developer Tools". Na barra onde tem as guias, no fim, clique na engrenagem de configuração.
Em GENERAL, marque a caixa "Disable Javascript" e atualize a página.
Isso fará com que o site seja carregado sem javascript.  Garanto que não vai ser uma coisa linda de ser ver!

O Javascript vai servir pra tantas coisas... Principalmente porque, por ser uma linguagem de programação, ele vai permitir comandos em cadeia, de forma procedural. O CSS não.

Quando começar a aprender javascript, vai ver como ele é importante.
Atualmente, todos os sites que eu desenvolvo tem, no mínimo, 4 chamadas de script na  e, às vezes, alguns internos ainda.